# ElasticSearch search by datetime field

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch

I need to do a search through multiple fields including a datetime field.

The search query may or may not contain date values specified in different formats:

- April 4
- 04/04/2013
- 2013-04-04

Query sting might contain some term that cannot be converted to date time.

Is there any way I can support that types of query using elastic search?

Answer (score 3):

Here what I dig up during my investigation:

I use [multi_field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/multi-field-type/) feature of Elastic search. I added string searchable text field for date type feature.

Here is the mapping I using for date type field:

```
   "TransactionDate":{
      "type":"multi_field",
      "fields":{
         "TransactionDate":{
            "type":"date",
            "format":"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||MM/dd/yyyy||yyyy/MM/dd",
            "index":"not_analyzed"
         },
         "formatted":{
            "type":"string",
            "index":"analyzed"
         }
      }
   }
```

Then I am able to include `TransactionDate.formatted` field to search query that using textual fields.

Hope that helps somebody else.

Comment: Do you really need the `multi_field` feature for this? According to the [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/date-format/) the `||` separator should be sufficient.